# How to fix : cannot find Module error in while running the npm run build command

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install, npm-run

In my application, npm run build command throws a module not found error as below:

```
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v16.17.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/

> @coreui/lutosa-obs@0.0.1 build C:\Users\Administrator\OneDrive\Documents\OSB-Frontend-production\Lutosa_front-end
> ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer --common-chunk --vendor-chunk --optimization --progress

'find_dp0' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\@angular\cli\bin\ng.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
}
```

I don't know what the wrong with my npm package. Please help me fix this.

I also attached my package.json file. I want to what are packages I need to install before using the npm run build error in my application.

- Package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "@coreui/lutosa-obs",
  "version": "0.00.1",
  "description": "Lutosa OBS Portal",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --first-only",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer --common-chunk --vendor-chunk --optimization --progress",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "prettier": "prettier --write \"{,!(node_modules|dist|build|coverage)/**/}*.{js,jsx,ts,json}\"",
    "pre-commit": "npm run lint && npm run prettier",
    "extract-i18n": "ngx-translate-extract --input ./src --output ./src/assets/i18n/{en,nl,fr,es,it,de}.json --format namespaced-json --sort"
  },
  "private": true,
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run pre-commit"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^11.1.0",
    "@coreui/angular": "~2.11.1",
    "@coreui/coreui": "^2.1.16",
    "@coreui/coreui-plugin-chartjs-custom-tooltips": "^1.3.1",
    "@coreui/icons": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
    "@coreui/icons-angular": "1.0.0-alpha.3",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.8.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.34",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@rxweb/reactive-form-validators": "^2.1.2",
    "@uiowa/digit-only": "^2.2.3",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^25.1.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^25.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "bs-stepper": "^1.7.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "cookieconsent": "^3.1.1",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "messageformat": "^2.3.0",
    "module_name": "^1.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
    "ng-lazyload-image": "9.1.0",
    "ngrx-store-localstorage": "^11.0.0",
    "ngx-avatar": "^4.1.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-cookieconsent": "^2.2.3",
    "ngx-editor": "^9.0.2",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^10.1.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^13.2.1",
    "ngx-translate-cache": "^9.0.2",
    "ngx-translate-messageformat-compiler": "^4.9.0",
    "primeflex": "^2.0.0",
    "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
    "primeng": "^11.2.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.5.5",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1101.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^11.1.0",
    "@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract": "^7.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.6.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.22",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "husky": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 10.13",
    "npm": ">= 6"
  }
}
```

Comment: check your npm version. You would probably need to upgrade the version

Answer (score 2):

First I want you to delete the "node module" folder and "package-lock.json" file and then

You can change the node version with the help of NVM

```
nvm install 14
nvm use 14
```

Now you can check the node version with

```
node --version
```

and then you can do

```
npm i -force
```

you modules will get installed

Comment: I don't get why they were not getting installed without `--force`. That did it though...

Answer (score 0):

The initialising npm error can be resolved by checking and trying a few things.

1. You have the latest versions of the npm and said packages
2. Try forcing the npm install using `npm i -f`
3. Try to audit the `npm modules` using `npm run audit` and fix the same

OR

Just delete all your npm files and reinstall them and then try the same.

Answer (score 0):

Check the directory index.js file shouldn't be in the src folder.
and run the command `node index.js` it will work.